# Big O complexity decision

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I got a big doubt regarding the complexity analysis of this code. I need to study the complexity of the "encontrarCaminos()" method and I'm torn between it being O(n*m) since it gets to iterate n times (thru an array.aslist (Caminos) finding all the simultaneous ways thru a maze -in which you can never go in a direction to a point you already passed-) and iterating it again another 6 times for each n due to all the directions you go thru.

n is the number of iterations for i and its increases.

m is the number of directions it checks, just to be clearer.

OR, it's O(n) because the 6 m times (directions) are a constant and therefore I can ignore em?.

Also, if I had to count all the cycles/instructions, where should I put the "cycles++;" counter for this method in particular? It's kinda related to my previous question, as determining its complexity will help with that.

Here is the piece of code in question:

http://pastebin.com/1mMGmigM

```
public void encontrarCaminos()
{
        boolean complete=false;
        int i=0;
        while(!complete)
        {
                for (Dir3D d: Dir3D.values())
                        {
                                Camino cAux = this.camino(i).copiar();
                                cAux.agregarDireccion(d);
                                Posicion pAux = cAux.posicionFinal();
                                if(chequearLimite(pAux) &&  this.get(pAux))
                                        {                                      
                                                this.agregarCamino(cAux);
                                                this.set(pAux, false);
                                        }
                        }
                        i++;                   
                        if( this.cantCaminos()==(this.xMap*this.yMap*this.zMap))
                                complete=true;
        }
        System.out.println(caminos);
}


//auxiliary things below, some of those are pretty straigthforward, but still.
###############################################################################
public boolean chequearLimite(Posicion p)
{
                return  0<=p.getX() && p.getX()<this.xMap
                &&      0<=p.getY() && p.getY()<this.yMap
                &&  0<=p.getZ() && p.getZ()<this.zMap;
}

##############################################################################
public int cantCaminos()
{
        return caminos.size();
}

###############################################################################

public void agregarDireccion(Dir3D dir)
{
        direcciones.add(dir);
        if (dir == Dir3D.ATRAS) posicionFinal.setY(posicionFinal.getY()-1);
        if (dir == Dir3D.DERECHA) posicionFinal.setX(posicionFinal.getX()+1);
        if (dir == Dir3D.ARRIBA) posicionFinal.setZ(posicionFinal.getZ()+1);
        if (dir == Dir3D.ADELANTE) posicionFinal.setY(posicionFinal.getY()+1);
        if (dir == Dir3D.IZQUIERDA) posicionFinal.setX(posicionFinal.getX()-1);
        if (dir == Dir3D.ABAJO) posicionFinal.setZ(posicionFinal.getZ()-1);
}

########################################################################################

public Camino copiar()
{
        Camino aux = new Camino(Posicion.copiar(posicionInicial));
        for (int i= 0;i<direcciones.size();i++)
        {
                aux.agregarDireccion(direcciones.get(i));
        }
        return aux;
}

########################################################################################

public Camino camino(Integer indice)
{
        return caminos.get(indice);
}
```

Any insight or help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tldr, but walking a graph is IMHO typically O(n log n) - n because there are n nodes, but log n due to back tracking etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: n is i, the number of iterations thru the while, which increase depending on the matrix size and if there is still a true in there waiting to be turned to false.
m would then be, the number of iterations it goes thru for the directions it has to check in the dir3D loop, aka: 6 (as there is such a number of directions to check for)

Comment: @Bohemian log(n) factors in schoolbook graph search algorithms are usually due to discarding a fixed fraction of your input and recursing -- none of that is going on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's refer to `this.xMap*this.yMap*this.zMap` as matrix-size.

It looks O((matrix-size)^2) to me. Since direcciones is being appended to some constant number of times per run of the outer loop, calls to copiar are O(matrix-size) in time. Then each loop iteration adds at most the size of `Dir3D` items (also a constant) to caminos. This continues until a total of matrix-size items have been added.

One thing I didnt check for was if it was possible to add more than matrix-size -- in which case you never terminate.

Comment: Yeah,      (this.xMap*this.yMap*this.zMap) would be the size of the matrix  and direcciones.size() does change, but only after that instruction when we add a direction.
Hence why I think the algorithm has a linear O(n) complexity as the number of instructions will escalate in an apparently linear way the bigger that array/matrix is. Thanks!

Comment: also, no, it's not possible to add more to that `this.xMap*this.yMap*this.zMap` we never modify it while the program is running. It's a constant value.

Comment: I mean if you agregarCamino too many times it might end up bigger than the matrix size in which case == is false.

Comment: Does direcciones ever get cleared out or does it just keep getting bigger? Because if it keeps getting bigger then copiar is not O(1) but O(matrix-size) and then this might be O(matrix-size^2)

Comment: ah, ok. And yeah, that never happens, caminos has always the same number of "roads" as the matrix has nodes/vectors, I guess it's kinda weird to explain, but it never gets to be bigger than that, so it's allright.

PS: and direcciones.size() is always bound as a constant to an specific road/camino, which is the number of directions it houses. So it does get cleared out.

Comment: Small edit on the previous comment to add a PS. Also, thanks a lot for the pointers and help, Alfred!

Comment: But the number of directions along a road could be pretty big, right? like taking a winding path that vists a lot of places? if so then it's O(matrix-size^2). What I mean is, to call this constant it needs to be one fixed constant that works for every road that is independent of the matrix-size.

Comment: Oh, you are right on that one, it's always increasing for each step taken in a direction (they also set a boolean as false), for each road iterated, until you fill matrix with falses. So, as you said before, it's O(matrix-size) for .copiar(), which then leads me to O(matrix-size^2) for encontrarCaminos()